# How to find the position of an entry within an array of hashes

Tags: ruby

I have the following hash:

```
locals_arr = [{:rank=>1, :id=>6}, {:rank=>2, :id=>8}, {:rank=>3, :id=>7}]
```

I am able to search for a specific entry by id using:

```
locals_arr.select{|x| x[:id].equal? 7}
```

which returns something like:

```
=> [{:rank=>3, :id=>7}]
```

Now I would like to know the position of this entry.

Sometimes I have a filtered set of ranks and need to know the rank within that set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Array#index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-find_index) for this.

```
locals_arr = [{:rank=>1, :id=>6}, {:rank=>2, :id=>8}, {:rank=>3, :id=>7}]

locals_arr.index{|h| h[:id]==6}
# => 0

locals_arr.index{|h| h[:id]== 8 }
# => 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
locals_arr.index({:rank=>3, :id=>7})
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html

Comment: You were actually in first, and answered my question, but Arup's answer cut out one step for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get both the index AND the object itself you can use `each_with_index` and then  jump out when you find the right one with `break`, like so:

```
irb(main):003:0> locals_arr = [{:rank=>1, :id=>6}, {:rank=>2, :id=>8}, {:rank=>3, :id=>7}]
irb(main):007:0> item, index = *locals_arr.each_with_index {|hash,i| break [hash,i] if hash[:id].equal? 7}
=> [{:rank=>3, :id=>7}, 2]
irb(main):008:0> item
=> {:rank=>3, :id=>7}
irb(main):009:0> index
=> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-index) metod:

```
 locals_arr = [{:rank=>1, :id=>6}, {:rank=>2, :id=>8}, {:rank=>3, :id=>7}]
 locols_arr.index(locals_arr.select{|x| x[:id].equal? 7}[0])
  # => 2
```

or shorter:

```
locals_arr.index{|e| e[:id] == 7}
# => 2
```

Comment: Your second approach is the one I first have chosen.. :)